# PHP MySQL Help - Database Not Updating

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry it's been a while since I've done some MySQL queries, so this is probably a really simple answer. Can someone please check this code and see why this isn't doing anything to the database

```
$Reference = "031";
$Message = "Test Message";

mysql_connect("localhost", "secretlol", "secretlol") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("db630112365") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("UPDATE quotes SET Body='$Message' WHERE Reference='$Reference';") or die(mysql_error());
```

Any ideas, would be greatly appreciated :)

I was thrown the following error:

> Unknown column '031' in 'where clause'

Yet, the value does exist.

Not sure if this helps:

Schema:

[image]

Values:

[image]

Comment: Obviously no rows match that criteria

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: @krunalnerikar values should ***never*** be backticked

Comment: what did `mysql_error()` throw back or does it ever make it there in the first place? and error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Error thrown back now is:     Unknown column '031' in 'where clause'

Comment: ^ There you go, @JohnConde was right from the get go.

Comment: I promise there is a row with the reference 031 though, and it's not updating

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think that error differs with John's comment. That error seems to indicate `$Reference` is being used as the column, not the value (which the code doesnt support).

Comment: @chris85 I deleted my comments; I honestly don't know where to throw myself here lol

Comment: We need to see the db schema for this.

Comment: Thanks @Chris85 that's what I thought. Surely the error would throw back saying something about a missing row, not a missing column?

Comment: @SteveDew Is this your actual query, or did you simplify it? The error messages suggests your where clause is different.

Comment: This is the actually query, I haven't simplified it.

Comment: @SteveDew You posted the schema; thanks. However, can you include some values that are in db? Make sure also that there is no whitespace, such as either leading or trailing. Plus, if you do have a value of `031`, then try changing it to `31` and then your `$Reference = "031";` to `$Reference = "31";` - If that works, then the `0` is an issue. Do a var_dump() to see what the query is also.

Comment: You're really close to use the [reserved word 'References'](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Tried removing the leading 0. Still throwing back the same error.

Comment: @JayBlanchard varchar(15)

Comment: You sure you chose the right database and/or table? I honestly don't know why what I suggested would not work. @SteveDew

Comment: are you absolutely sure the SQL statement above is exactly what you have in your application?  I set this up and tried it, as you have it posted and it works fine.  The error being thrown indicates that you're trying to access a column named '031', not the value, as if you'd done something like `"UPDATE quotes SET Body='$Message' WHERE $Reference='whatever';"`

Comment: @RobertWade Promise the query is:    mysql_query("UPDATE quotes SET Body='$Message' WHERE Reference='$Reference';") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that maybe you have a PHP Constant named Reference in your application.  Would that be a possibility? If you're defining 'Reference' as a constant, it would be accessible as just "Reference" without the "$", therefore 'Reference' in your where clause would be substituted with '031' which would explain why its failing on a column named '031'.  Try changing your variable name to something else, and see if it fixes it.

Comment: I have no idea what I have done, but this is no working perfectly?

Comment: Write your SQL statement to a variable and echo it out on the page and see what it looks like, then share it with us.

Comment: Ok, yes apologies folks, it seems those leading 00's were causing the problem. I am now stripping them out. Thank you all very much for your help!

Comment: which is what I wrote originally wrote earlier *"Plus, if you do have a value of 031, then try changing it to 31 and then your $Reference = "031"; to $Reference = "31"; - If that works, **then the 0 is an issue.** Do a var_dump() to see what the query is also."* and is probably treated as an octal, where I deleted a comment about that earlier. @SteveDew So I was right from the get go myself.

Comment: This still doesn't explain the error though. Weird.

Comment: @RobertWade There is a reason. See one of John Conde's answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/11165118/1415724 it has something to do with how MySQL stores varchar characters with leading zeros. Zerofill is the clincher here. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/37528724/1415724

Comment: @SteveDew You could have CAST'ed it which would have worked. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html and http://stackoverflow.com/a/37528724/1415724

Comment: Very interesting.  I set up a demo in MySQL workbench based exactly off of his schema, and it worked fine.  I guess i get what you're saying... I just still don't understand why the column name error based off what he was using.  It seems like the 'wrong' error in this case.  It would seem like the error in that case would be more like `Row with Reference 031 not found` as opposed to `unknown column 031`.

Comment: @SteveDew I posted an answer below for you to mark the question as solved. I posted it as a community wiki since I didn't want rep from this.

Answer (score 0):

Posting as a community wiki, since the issue was found in comments, being the leading zeros.

What you could have done also was to CAST it.

References:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html
- [How to check varchar with leading zeros in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37528367/how-to-check-varchar-with-leading-zeros-in-mysql)

The leading zero could very well be treated as an octal by MySQL and is being ignored.

Therefore, it's best not to store leading zeros as a row's value. I would suggest using an `int` type if you're going to be using integers for storage values.

You can always alter the column's type for this.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html